# jQuery addClass to current page nav not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, addclass, internet-explorer-7

**Update** Thanks to @mrtsherman verifying my code was fine, I dove into the CSS and found that for no reason in particular, ie7 wanted a bit of extra padding on the bottom. This is why I hate ie7.

I have some pretty simple code automatically adding a class to the nav item corresponding with the current page. Works fine in all browser including ie8 and ie9 but seems to just not function in ie7. Who's broken, ie7 or me?

html:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li class="navitem"><a href="about.html">about us</a></li><!--navitems-->
<li class="navitem"><a href="purchase.html">purchase</a></li><!--navitems-->
<li class="navitem"><a href="sales.html">sales</a></li><!--navitems-->
<li class="navitem"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li><!--navitems-->
</ul>
</div><!--navbar-->
```

js file

```
$(function(){
        var full_url = document.URL; 
        var url_array = full_url.split('/')
        var $last_segment = url_array[url_array.length-1]; 
        $('#navbar li a').each(function(){
            var $href = $(this).attr('href');
            if ( ($href == $last_segment) || ($href == '') ) {
                $(this).addClass('curr');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('curr');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: As your example works in a fiddle it seems that your problem may lie elsewhere. IE7 Quirks or Standards (though I tested both and both worked)?

Comment: Are you sure its not because in IE7 there is a trailing slash in the url? This would cause `$last_segment` to be a blank string. Therefore making it execute the removeClass code always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I think about it, the more I think the problem must have to do with the split of your url. If there is a trailing slash then the `$last_segment` will be an empty string, thus never matching. You should check and trim that before splitting.

http://jsfiddle.net/zGbJx/2/

```
var full_url = "http://www.mysite.com/contacts.html/";
var full_url = "http://www.mysite.com/contacts.html";
//trim trailing slash
if (full_url.charAt(full_url.length - 1) == '/') {
    full_url = full_url.substring(0, full_url.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Just checking over it, no trailing slashes so I don't think that is causing my issue. I would assume that would cause a problem in other browsers besides ie7 any way.

Comment: @user1161032 - yes it would fail in other browsers. I updated the link to my fiddle. If you test it in IE7 the code works just fine. If you see differently let me know. Contacts should be red.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with i.e.& running jsfiddle. The first example does work. I tried in my code but the results, again, worked fine everywhere but ie7.

Comment: for the sake of argument, the only difference between your example and my actual code is I'm using `document.URL` and you're using a url string. Does ie7 not like `document.url` maybe?

Comment: @user1161032 - I think the only question is - does IE7 have a trailing slash? Perhaps IE7 likes to append one to document url. Maybe in your testing you appended it. Maybe IE7 appends it automatically on navigation. I don't really know, and not to be rude, but I don't really care. It's a dead browser.

Comment: @user1161032 - if it worked on jsfiddle and not in your actual code -then something else is breaking somewhere else.

Comment: Totally agree. I hate ie7 with a passion but can't ignore it as this is for a business site that caters to the older demographic (read outdated tech users). I did go through and check ie7 for a trailing slash and it is for sure not there. Tried adding one manually and it just returns a 404. However you are quite correct, it should be working, so it must be elsewhere in either my css or other code. Glad you could help me make sure it wasn't in this code though. Thanks!!

Comment: I was racking my brain as to why the code worked everywhere but ie7. Thanks for proving the code was fine. Tore apart the CSS and found that ie7 wanted a worthless tweak to the navitem class. Thanks again tho.